# MySQL case when in stored procedure not working as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is a stored procedure that has 3 possible cases.  I can't figure out how to get the 3rd case to run.  If I swap 2 and 3, 3 will run fine and 2 won't run, which leads me to believe it's not the actual code within each case.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`ip` PROCEDURE `api_userLogin_new`(IN _userType int,IN _clientId varchar(45),IN _username varchar(50))
    BEGIN
        CASE WHEN _userType = 1
           THEN
              *do stuff that works*
        WHEN '2'
           THEN 
              *do other stuff that works*
        WHEN '3'
           THEN 
              {this won't run, but does if I swap it out with 2}
        ELSE BEGIN END;
        END CASE;
    END;
```

It doesn't give an error, but it just doesn't do anything no matter which code is in the last of the 3 positions (i.e. move "WHEN '3'" and it's code up to where WHEN '2' is, and then 2 wont' run or error).

Comment: Use the full expression. `_userType = '2'  WHEN _userType = '3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full expression:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`ip` PROCEDURE `api_userLogin_new`(IN _userType int,IN _clientId varchar(45),IN _username varchar(50))
    BEGIN
        CASE WHEN _userType = 1
           THEN
              *do stuff that works*
        WHEN _userType = '2'
           THEN 
              *do other stuff that works*
        WHEN _userType  = '3'
           THEN 
              *do other stuff that works*
        ELSE BEGIN END;
        END CASE;
    END;
```

Side note: Your scenario was occurring since '2' and '3' evaluate to TRUE in MYSQL.

Comment: Thank you!  Missed that you could not mix when syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed the two possible `CASE WHEN` syntax descibed [on the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html). You can use the following solution using the variable only on the `CASE`:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `user`@`ip` PROCEDURE `api_userLogin_new`(IN _userType INT, IN _clientId VARCHAR(45), IN _username VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  CASE _userType
    WHEN 1 THEN
      -- do something
    WHEN 2 THEN 
      -- do something
    WHEN 3 THEN 
      -- do something
    ELSE
      BEGIN END;
  END CASE;
END;
```

... or the following solution using the variable on every `WHEN` (instead once on the `CASE`):

```
CREATE DEFINER = `user`@`ip` PROCEDURE `api_userLogin_new`(IN _userType INT, IN _clientId VARCHAR(45), IN _username VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN _userType = 1 THEN
      -- do something
    WHEN _userType = 2 THEN 
      -- do something
    WHEN _userType = 3 THEN 
      -- do something
    ELSE 
      BEGIN END;
  END CASE;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak to code which I can see, not that I can't, but I see a few potential problems with your code.  First, every predicate of the `CASE` expression should end with a delimiter.  Also, if you don't have an `ELSE` condition, then don't include one.  So I recommend this version:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`ip` PROCEDURE `api_userLogin_new`(IN _userType int,IN _clientId varchar(45),IN _username varchar(50))
    BEGIN
        CASE _userType WHEN 1
             THEN *do stuff that works*;
             WHEN 2
             THEN *do other stuff that works*;
             WHEN 3
             THEN {this won't run, but does if I swap it out with 2};
        END CASE;
    END;
```